# responsive constraint layout dentro del constraint principal

Tags: android-studio, constraint-layout

Anexo la imagen para poder explicarme mejor de lo que estoy queriendo implementar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El *constraint layout principal* es de color oscuro, el semicírculo, es un *xml* con este código:

```
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#2F2F28"/>
        <size
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="60dp"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="240dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="240dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Y la parte blanca es otro *constraint layout agregado*. Cabe destacar que en los dos layout tengo algunas views, como ser *imageview*, *button* y *textview*. Ahora bien, el problema es que el *constraint layout secundario*, osea el blanco, no es *responsive*, ni su contenido por supuesto, acarreando el problema de que en varios dispositivos de diferente tamaño no se adapta.

Este formato es el que preciso, pero si alguien puede conseguirlo de otra manera o hay alguna mejor forma de hacerlo soy todo oídos, de todas formas me gustaría saber porque esto no esta andando. muchas gracias amigos.

Aquí va el *xml* del *layout* en cuestión.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorMultimedia">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descImage"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/live" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_slideshow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/trans_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="417dp"
    android:layout_height="544dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorMultimedia2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trans_btn1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mediocirculo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="212dp"
        android:layout_height="169dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/mic_text"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="206dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/micc" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/trans_btn2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="114dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logop" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/trans_btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/trans_btn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_slideshow" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: deberias agregar el xml del layout sino es imposible saber por que no es responsive

Comment: en seguida lo agrego, muchas gracias erick